# How to solve TIME_WAIT state issue when in multiple concurrency?

Tags: database, go

If I run below example on Windows I will quickly hit TCP connection limit (which I set to 64k) and get error: `dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connectex: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.`

I see all this `TIME_WAIT` states waiting for there lifetime to end with: `netstat -ano|findstr 3306`

Why aren't connections closed immediately?

The code:

```
package main

import (
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "log"
    "sync"
)

var (
    db_instance *sqlx.DB
    wg          sync.WaitGroup
)

func main() {
    db, err := sqlx.Connect("mysql", "user:pass@/table")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
    db_instance = db

    for {
        for l := 0; l < 50; l++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go DB_TEST()
        }
        wg.Wait()
    }
}

func DB_TEST() {
    defer wg.Done()

    var s string
    err := db_instance.QueryRow("SELECT NOW()").Scan(&s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    log.Println(s)
}
```

Comment: because you do a `defer db.Close()` in `main()` and that is only executed when your program stops.

Comment: @RickyA: isn't that ok? to close db connection at the end of the program... Where would you close connection to the db?

Comment: Closing it is ok, but I was just answering your question about why It doesnt get closed. I am not familiar with that package, so maybe it wants the connection closed after each call, or it keeps a pool of connections internally. That should be in the docs.

Comment: @Glavić You're closing db at the end of the program, that's correct. Please refer [this article](https://www.vividcortex.com/blog/2015/09/22/common-pitfalls-go/) to get insights on measures to take. Also I recommend you to use `db.Prepare(query string) (*Stmt, error)` and than `stmt.Query` or `stmt.Exec` and than`stmt.Close` to reuse connections. Also set `SetMaxOpenConns` and `SetMaxIdleConns`. If needed use `SetConnMaxLifetime` too. This way you can keep `TIME_WAIT` status and connections under control.

Comment: @Glavić FYI Chaining `db.QueryRow("SELECT NOW()").Scan(&s)` does [closes connection](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/database/sql/sql.go#L2789) internally. Wondering why it is not happening for you.

Comment: @jeevatkm: I know, I already checked that pice of code. I also read that article yesterday. Let me try `SetMax***Conns`...

Comment: @jeevatkm: I set `10` to `Open` and `Max` and it is working now with only 10 connections, no `TIME_WAIT` anymore... Do you maybe know what happens if there are 50+ requests on DB, at the same time, and I only have max connections set to 10?

Comment: @Glavić you will get panic when query unable to get connection. Typically connections get reused quickly. I recommend you to do sampling for your app and then set upper bound in SetMaxOpen* along with SetMaxIdle*. For e.g. 50 and 5.

Comment: @jeevatkm: I did some testing, with 5000 concurrent calls to db INSERT with 1 max connection. There was no error, and inserts were flying in. But to be sure I will open a few more connection to be sure. Tnx for the help!

Comment: @Glavić you're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drafting answer from my comments discussion with @Glavić.

Utilize the `SetMaxOpenConns` and `SetMaxIdleConns` settings to keep `TIME_WAIT` status and connections under control. If needed use `SetConnMaxLifetime` too, generally it's not needed.